# Error with Leaflet Tutorial on adding Mapbox tile layer

Tags: leaflet, tiles, mapbox

I'm trying to add a Mapbox Classic base layer from my account using Leaflet's tutorial. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code:

```html
<div id='map' ></div>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([39.952451, -75.163459], 15);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={token}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>'
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'XXX',
    token: 'XXX'
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
```

Comment: Open up your browser's developer tools (F12 on most browsers) and look at the console output. Are there any errors showing up?

Comment: thanks for the tip. says there's Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list on the L.tileLayer line, but the Leaflet tutorial code shows no )

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your parentheses, but you are still missing a comma after your attribution line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error when declaring the object properties.

Do **not** do this:

```js
var options = {
  maxZoom: 18,
  id = 'kirsten',
  token = 'abcdefghijklm'
}
```

Do this instead:

```js
var options = {
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'kirsten',
  token: 'abcdefghijklm'
}
```

Note `=` vs `:`, and read the [docs on object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Object_literals) while you're at it.

Comment: fixed, but still another error